# In extjs how to make the columns by default not visible,as when user is opening first time it is showing all the columns?

Tags: extjs

When I am opening my webpage,all the columns are by default showed up, I dont want to show them by default,if user want to se ,he can tick that column and see.
Here is my code:

```
  header: "ace",
    width: 50,
    dataIndex: "ace"
},{
    header: "",
    width: ,
    id: "",     
    dataIndex: "ace1"
},{
    header: "s",
    width: 50,
    id: "s",
    dataIndex: "f"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`hidden`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-hidden):

> `true` to hide the component.

For example:

```
{
  header: "Case Count",
  width: 50,
  renderer: LNK,
  dataIndex: "case_count",
  hidden: true
}
```

Comment: @ace: If it helped you - please consider accepting the answer.